# Where can I find a recently installed Photoshop plugin?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, plugin

Please help me, I have been looking through Photoshop for an hour like an idiot, I just installed [this plugin](http://www.cutandslice.me/) and I can't find it where it is. Where would it be located?

Comment: Try `Window > Extensions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you correctly installed it via Adobe Extension Manager, in Photoshop, go to
`Window > Extensions > Cut and Slice me`.
It's mentioned in the description of `CutAndSliceMe` in Adobe Extension Manager.